# PHP Get only select key values in a multidimensional php array with variable size?

Tags: php, arrays

With a multidimensional array of dynamic length, how can I get an array of just the specefic key values.

Let's say I just want color values.

```
0  {
        color => green,
        size => large,
}
1 {
        color => green,
        size => small,
    }
2 {
        color => orange,
        size => small,
    }
```

For example the desired output for that array would be:
{green,green,orange}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$colors = [];
foreach ($in_array as $item) {
    $colors[] = $item['color'];
}
```

is a pretty conventional way, but since PHP 5.5 you can also do something like this:

```
$colors = array_column($in_array, 'color');
```

The second way is more human readable, and over small datasets, the performance difference is negligible, but it is worth noting that foreach is marginally more efficient than array_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

`array_map` calls a function with every given item in the second argument, returns an array of what the function returned.

```
function getColors($item)
{
    return($item['color']);
}
$colors = array_map("getColors", $array); // ['green', 'green', 'orange']
```